# how to get the actual address of `func` from `callq func@PLT`

Tags: linux, function, assembly, shared-libraries

In my Linux program, I need a function that takes an address `addr` and checks whether a `callq` instruction placed at `addr` is calling an specific function `func` loaded from a shared library. I mean, I need to check whether I have something like `callq func@PLT` at `addr`.

So, on Linux, how to reach the real address of a function `func` from a `callq func@PLT` instruction?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can only find out about that at runtime, after the dynamic linker *resolves* the actual load address.
Warning: What follows is slightly deeper magic ...

To illustrate what's happening use a debugger:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) { printf("Hello, World!\n"); return 0; }
```

Compile it (`gcc -O8 ...`). `objdump -d` on the binary shows (the optimization of `printf()` being substituted with `puts()` for a plain string not withstanding ...):

```
Disassembly of section .init:
[ ... ]
Disassembly of section .plt:

0000000000400408 <__libc_start_main@plt-0x10>:
  400408:  ff 35 a2 04 10 00       pushq  1049762(%rip)        # 5008b0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x8>>
  40040e:  ff 25 a4 04 10 00       jmpq   *1049764(%rip)        # 5008b8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x10>
[ ... ]
0000000000400428 <puts@plt>:
  400428:  ff 25 9a 04 10 00       jmpq   *1049754(%rip)   # 5008c8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+0x20>
  40042e:  68 01 00 00 00          pushq  $0x1
  400433:  e9 d0 ff ff ff          jmpq   400408 <_init+0x18>
[ ... ]
0000000000400500 <main>:
  400500:  48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  400504:  bf 0c 06 40 00          mov    $0x40060c,%edi
  400509:  e8 1a ff ff ff          callq  400428 <puts@plt>
  40050e:  31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  400510:  48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
  400514:  c3                      retq
```

Now load it into `gdb`. Then:

```
$ gdb ./tcc
GNU gdb Red Hat Linux (6.3.0.0-0.30.1rh)
[ ... ]
(gdb) x/3i 0x400428
0x400428:       jmpq   *1049754(%rip)        # 0x5008c8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+32>
0x40042e:       pushq  $0x1
0x400433:       jmpq   0x400408
(gdb) x/gx 0x5008c8
0x5008c8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+32>:    0x000000000040042e
```

Notice this value points back to the instruction directly following the first `jmpq`; this means the `puts@plt` slot, on first invocation, will simply "fall through" to:

```
(gdb) x/3i 0x400408
0x400408:       pushq  1049762(%rip)        # 0x5008b0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+8>
0x40040e:       jmpq   *1049764(%rip)        # 0x5008b8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+16>
0x400414:       nop
(gdb) x/gx 0x5008b0
0x5008b0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+8>:     0x0000000000000000
(gdb) x/gx 0x5008b8
0x5008b8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+16>:    0x0000000000000000
```

The function address and argument aren't initialized yet.
This is the state just after program load, but before executing. Now start executing it:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400500
(gdb) run
Starting program: tcc
(no debugging symbols found)
(no debugging symbols found)

Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000400500 in main ()
(gdb)  x/i 0x400428
0x400428:  jmpq   *1049754(%rip)        # 0x5008c8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+32>
(gdb) x/gx 0x5008c8
0x5008c8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+32>:    0x000000000040042e
```

So this hasn't changed *yet* - but the *targets* (the `GOT` contents for the `libc` initialization) are different now:

```
(gdb) x/gx 0x5008b0
0x5008b0 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+8>:     0x0000002a9566b9a8
(gdb) x/gx 0x5008b8
0x5008b8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+16>:    0x0000002a955609f0
(gdb) disas 0x0000002a955609f0
Dump of assembler code for function _dl_runtime_resolve:
0x0000002a955609f0 <_dl_runtime_resolve+0>:     sub    $0x38,%rsp
[ ... ]
```

I.e. at program load time, the dynamic linker will resolve the "`init`" parts first. It substitutes the `GOT` references with pointers that redirect into the dynamic linking code.

Therefore, when first calling an external-to-the-binary function through the `.plt` reference, it'll jump into the linker again. Let it do that, then inspect the program after that - the state has changed again:

```
(gdb) break *0x0000000000400514
Breakpoint 2 at 0x400514
(gdb) continue
Continuing.
Hello, World!

Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000400514 in main ()
(gdb) x/i 0x400428
0x400428:  jmpq   *1049754(%rip)        # 0x5008c8 <_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_+32>
(gdb) x/gx 0x5008c8
0x5008c8 :    0x0000002a956c8870
(gdb) disas 0x0000002a956c8870
Dump of assembler code for function puts:
0x0000002a956c8870 <puts+0>:    mov    %rbx,0xffffffffffffffe0(%rsp)
[ ... ]
```

So there's your redirect right into `libc` now - the `PLT` reference to `puts()` finally got resolved.

The instructions to the linker *where to insert the actual function load addresses* (that we've seen it do for `_dl_runtime_resolve` comes from special sections in the ELF binary:

```
$ readelf -a tcc
[ ... ]
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
[ ... ]
  INTERP         0x0000000000000200 0x0000000000400200 0x0000000000400200
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
[ ... ]
Dynamic section at offset 0x700 contains 21 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
[ ... ]
Relocation section '.rela.plt' at offset 0x3c0 contains 2 entries:
  Offset          Info           Type           Sym. Value    Sym. Name + Addend
0000005008c0  000100000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 __libc_start_main + 0
0000005008c8  000200000007 R_X86_64_JUMP_SLO 0000000000000000 puts + 0
```

There's more to ELF than just the above, but these three pieces tell the kernel's binary format handler "this ELF binary has an *interpreter*" (which is the dynamic linker) that needs to be loaded / initialized first, that it *requires* `libc.so.6`, and that offsets `0x5008c0` and `0x5008c8` in the program's writeable data section must be *substituted* by the load addresses for `__libc_start_main` and `puts`, respectively, when the step of dynamic linking is actually performed.

How exactly that happens, from ELF's point of view, is up to the details of the *interpreter* (aka, the dynamic linker implementation).

Comment: Thank you very much for this full-illustrated example. It's very clear, but I have another question: is there any way to resolve a specific function when the program is loaded, I mean do you know any gcc attribute to make a function non-lazily-resolved? Because, if I really got it, a function must be first-time called to have its address resolved. However, in my program, I need to know whether a specific function `func` is going to be executed after the current one. But, `func`may not have been called before, so that its reference at PLT may not have been resolved.

Comment: Yes there is; I've left that out in my last paragraph, linker implementation details ... but it's documented, see the `LD_BIND_NOW` environment variable in the manpage for `ld.so`, http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

Comment: `LD_BIND_NOW` seems to do what I need, but it resolves all the symbols and I need only one to be resolved. So `LD_BIND_NOW` may cause unnecessary overhead. Do you know any way to bind only a specific function at loading time?

Comment: I would "trick" the program into calling that function once _before_ `main()`, by putting a call to it into a constructor section or something like that. Not aware of any method to restrict `LD_BIND_NOW` to specific symbols only, sorry :(

Comment: What a pitty! Calling that function before `main()` will make only the program's own PLT to be updated, but I need any other dynamically linked or loaded library's PLT to be updated too. Any way, thank you.